# MySQL trigger update syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers

I wander to set a trigger after update , and if the number of `product.Quanity` less then 200 , it will be 200. And it's my code , how can i improve it?

The error message said that the error at line 4.

```
IF  (SELECT product.Quanity<200)
THEN
UPDATE product
SET product.Quanity = 200
```

Using phpmyadmin - sql

Comment: first of all, you need to tell us what database engine you are using

Comment: sorry , i 'd updated the question , and my engine is phpmyadmin-sql

Comment: that's not a database engine. Are you using MySQL?, SQL Server?, Oracle?, Postgresql?

Comment: If you're using **PhpMyAdmin** to work with your database, then you're working with **MySQL** - not (Microsoft) SQL Server .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo need use where for solve.

```
UPDATE product
SET product.Quanity = 200
WHERE product.Quanity < 200
```

:-D